# FullSimplify does not simplify at all

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have some problems simplifying things with `FullSimplify`. Suppose a matrix `W = {{c[1, 1],c[1, 2],c[1, 3]}, {c[1, 2],c[2, 2],c[2, 3]},{c[1, 3],c[2, 3],c[3, 3]}}` which has to be unitary, so there are conditions on the c's. I declare my conditions as
`cond ={{(Abs[c[1, 1]]^2+Abs[c[1, 2]]^2+Abs[c[1, 3]]^2)->1,(c[1, 2] Conjugate[c[1, 1]]+c[2, 2] Conjugate[c[1, 2]]+c[2, 3] Conjugate[c[1, 3]])->0,(c[1, 3] Conjugate[c[1, 1]]+c[2, 3] Conjugate[c[1, 2]]+c[3, 3] Conjugate[c[1, 3]])->0,(c[1, 1] Conjugate[c[1, 2]]+c[1, 2] Conjugate[c[2, 2]]+c[1, 3] Conjugate[c[2, 3]])->0,(Abs[c[1, 2]]^2+Abs[c[2, 2]]^2+Abs[c[2, 3]]^2)->1,(c[1, 3] Conjugate[c[1, 2]]+c[2, 3] Conjugate[c[2, 2]]+c[3, 3] Conjugate[c[2, 3]])->0,(c[1, 1] Conjugate[c[1, 3]]+c[1, 2] Conjugate[c[2, 3]]+c[1, 3] Conjugate[c[3, 3]])->0,(c[1, 2] Conjugate[c[1, 3]]+c[2, 2] Conjugate[c[2, 3]]+c[2, 3] Conjugate[c[3, 3]])->0,(Abs[c[1, 3]]^2 + Abs[c[2, 3]]^2+Abs[c[3, 3]]^2->1)}}` 
Then, I want to diagonalize the following matrix `S = 1/3 {{-1, 2, 2}, {2, -1, 2}, {2, 2, -1}}` and I want that the diagonal matrix has the form `diagS=DiagonalMatrix[{1,-1,-1}]` so I use
`FullSimplify[ConjugateTranspose[W].S.W - DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1, -1}], 
 /.Flatten[cond]]`
I get
`{{1/3 (-3 - Abs[c[1, 1]]^2 - Abs[c[1, 2]]^2 - Abs[c[1, 3]]^2 + 2 (c[1, 2] + c[1, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 1]] + 2 (c[1, 1] + c[1, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 2]] + 2 (c[1, 1] + c[1, 2]) Conjugate[c[1, 3]]),1/3 ((-c[1, 2] + 2 (c[2, 2] + c[2, 3])) Conjugate[c[1, 1]] + (2 c[1, 2] - c[2, 2] + 2 c[2, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 2]] + (2 (c[1, 2] + c[2, 2]) - c[2, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 3]]),1/3 ((-c[1, 3] + 2 (c[2, 3] + c[3, 3])) Conjugate[c[1, 1]] + (2 c[1, 3] - c[2, 3] + 2 c[3, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 2]] + (2 (c[1, 3] + c[2, 3]) - c[3, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 3]])}, {1/3 ((-c[1, 1] + 2 (c[1, 2] + c[1, 3])) Conjugate[c[1, 2]] + (2 c[1, 1] - c[1, 2] + 2 c[1, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 2]] + (2 (c[1, 1] + c[1, 2]) - c[1, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 3]]), 1/3 (3 - Abs[c[1, 2]]^2 - Abs[c[2, 2]]^2 - Abs[c[2, 3]]^2 + 2 (c[2, 2] + c[2, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 2]] + 2 (c[1, 2] + c[2, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 2]] + 2 (c[1, 2] + c[2, 2]) Conjugate[c[2, 3]]), 1/3 ((-c[1, 3] + 2 (c[2, 3] + c[3, 3])) Conjugate[c[1, 2]] + (2 c[1, 3] - c[2, 3] + 2 c[3, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 2]] + (2 (c[1, 3] + c[2, 3]) - c[3, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 3]])}, {1/3 ((-c[1, 1] + 2 (c[1, 2] + c[1, 3])) Conjugate[c[1, 3]] + (2 c[1, 1] - c[1, 2] + 2 c[1, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 3]] + (2 (c[1, 1] + c[1, 2]) - c[1, 3]) Conjugate[c[3, 3]]),1/3 ((-c[1, 2] + 2 (c[2, 2] + c[2, 3])) Conjugate[c[1, 3]] + (2 c[1, 2] - c[2, 2] + 2 c[2, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 3]] + (2 (c[1, 2] + c[2, 2]) - c[2, 3]) Conjugate[c[3, 3]]),1/3 (3 - Abs[c[1, 3]]^2 - Abs[c[2, 3]]^2 - Abs[c[3, 3]]^2 + 2 (c[2, 3] + c[3, 3]) Conjugate[c[1, 3]] + 2 (c[1, 3] + c[3, 3]) Conjugate[c[2, 3]] + 2 (c[1, 3] + c[2, 3]) Conjugate[c[3, 3]])}}`
Clearly, `FullSimplify` is not using my conditions since `-Abs[c[1, 1]]^2 - Abs[c[1, 2]]^2 - Abs[c[1, 3]]^2 = -1`
Maybe I am not using `FullSimplify` correctly, so I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not try in a simpler setting first? Work with 2D matrices where things are simpler, get that functioning, and then expand to your real problem.

Comment: Maybe read about `ComplexExpand`.